# Can I program Tasker-like programs to do stuff if specific WiFi network is in range?

Tags: wi-fi, tasker, task-management, llama

I'd like to try out Tasker, Llama or some such automated program.

However, I do NOT want to program events based on GPS or other location information (for a variety of reasons not germane to this question).

Is there a way to trigger tasks in Tasker or some equivalent program based on the fact that a WiFi network with a specific SSID (or other signature) is in range or goes out of range?

To clarify: one of the main tasks is to turn on/off my WiFi when I float in/out of the range of known networks. Therefore, merely being in range should be the trigger, NOT connected to the network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In Tasker create a new `State` based context and choose `Net` as
   state category.
   [image] [image]
2. Then choose `Wifi Near` as net action:

   [image] [image]

This will bring a screen where you can input data about the WiFi access point you are interested in. If you are near the desired WiFi access point then you could just press the scan button (the button with lens symbol at left end of the text `SSID`).

[image]

This scans the near by access points and lists its details. Simply select the one which you are interested in.  Now you are good to go to add an entry task and exit task to whatever you want.

Comment: Narayanan, you should update your Tasker app :) Today's screens look a lot different (Holo-UI). But +1 for the answer – that's how I would do it, too.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, the Tasker has different versions for 4.0+ devices and 1.6+ devices - just FYI. The screen shots were taken from my mobile running Tasker 1.6u2m on Android v2.3.3 and the Holo-UI are in v4.1+. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yo. Nes. Partly. I have the holo UI on 4.0.3 already, so it's not 4.1+. But yes, right after placing my comment I thought that might be the case. Need to check with my old Droid² which still runs 2.3.7 whether it updated to Holo UI – but I remember exactly that thing with some other apps (Holo on 4+, old interface on GB). // So let's replace my previous comment with a hint that on newer Android versions (most likely 4.0+) screenshots would look different :)

Comment: Nay. Yay. IIRC Tasker got a revamp for holo, using ActionBarSherlock(ABS) for older platforms < ICS :)

Answer (score 2):

In Short: Both Llama and Tasker have the WiFi Network Connected/Disconnected State where you may trigger tasks/actions. Tasker also has a WiFi Near state so that you do not have to be connected to a network for a task to trigger, whereas Llama does not.

Comment: "WiFi Network Connected/Disconnected" is definitely NOT what I asked about, given that the task I want is to turn on/off WiFi when I'm in range of a known WiFi network :)  Does near state in Tasker know the difference between networks, or simply whether one exists in range?

Comment: @DVK My apologies! The way you worded your question suggested otherwise. Tasker does know the difference between networks - when you create a profile with the WiFi Near state you will get a list of multiple networks in range that you may choose from. If you are not in range you can input the SSID manually (and optionally the MAC of the network, which I would recommend doing). I've created a test profile with what you want to do and I can confirm that it works.